# android - the variable mTwoPane in master detail doesn't change

Tags: android, android-layout, master-detail, android-orientation

I'm trying to use masterDetail layout changing as minus as possible, trying to understand their default structure.

I'm trying app on my Samsung S5.

The app work normally, but in landscape mode doesn't add the fragment in the right part of layout.

I think the problem is that the variable mTwoPane doesn't change the value, remain false, this because findViewById(R.id.pokemon_detail_container) != null evidently is ever false.

This is the code:

the block inside onCreate in MainActivity:

```
        if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
        // If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
    }
```

the comments are default.

The detail_conter in activity_detail.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.soissy.masterdetail.DetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

This is the code point where if mTwoPane is true, i add the fragment. This method is inside a inner class inside MainActivity:

```
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setImageResource(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mNameView.setText(mValues.get(position).name);


        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mTwoPane) Log.d("mTwoPane", "is true");
                else Log.d("mTwoPane", "is false");
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putInt(DetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't understand what I've to do to add the fragment(mTwoPane=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When you create with Android Studio a MasterDetail "activity" at the beginning, it automatically creates a layout for two pane mode. However, i think only for tablets because the specific options of this layout are "w900dp". So I created another layout for landscape mode. Then copied and pasted from layout "with w900dp" to my new layout with landscape orientation, and now all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be selecting the layout that you think you are. Make sure you are following this documentation on how to [Support Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). A simple way to test to see if Android is selecting the layout you are expecting, is to change something in that layout file, and only that file, that will be obvious to you when displayed - a color or text, for example. If you don't see the change, then you are not looking at the layout you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of boolean always false  but in my case , I have I the adapter as a Separate java file so Implemented a instance callbck in my list fragment and then I. Moved the this

if findViewById R.id.detail_container !=null 
    mTwoPane = true;

Into my onclick call back before the If(mTwopane). And it worked now I can view Twopane in landscape and when I flip to portrait. The detail actvity kicks in so this ment that the condition of checking if the view was != null was not being run , that why the boolean stayed false I hope this helps some one